# How to show custom metadata on the frontend wit WP Store Locator?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, google-maps

I want to add a custom text on the info windows below the Store information (below Email).

[image: example]

I am following the instruction from:

https://wpstorelocator.co/document/add-custom-meta-data-to-store-locations/

So, I added the following on the function.php file of the worpress theme:

```
// adding my_textinput field
add_filter( 'wpsl_meta_box_fields', 'custom_meta_box_fields' );

function custom_meta_box_fields( $meta_fields ) {

    $meta_fields[__( 'Additional Information', 'wpsl' )] = array(
        'phone' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Tel', 'wpsl' )
        ),
        'fax' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Fax', 'wpsl' )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Email', 'wpsl' )
        ),
        'url' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Url', 'wpsl' )
        ),
        'my_textinput' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Textinput', 'wpsl' )
        )
    );

    return $meta_fields;
}

// add my_textinput in to the json response
function custom_frontend_meta_fields( $store_fields ) {

    $store_fields['wpsl_my_textinput'] = array( 
        'name' => 'my_textinput',
        'type' => 'text'
    );

    return $store_fields;
}


// show my_textinput into the frontend on info window
add_filter( 'wpsl_info_window_template', 'custom_info_window_template' );

function custom_info_window_template() {

    global $wpsl_settings, $wpsl;

    $info_window_template = '<div data-store-id="<%= id %>" class="wpsl-info-window">' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<p>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t\t" .  wpsl_store_header_template() . "\r\n";  
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t\t" . '<span><%= address %></span>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t\t" . '<% if ( address2 ) { %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t\t" . '<span><%= address2 %></span>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t\t" . '<% } %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t\t" . '<span>' . wpsl_address_format_placeholders() . '</span>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '</p>' . "\r\n";

    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% if ( phone ) { %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<span><strong>' . esc_html( $wpsl->i18n->get_translation( 'phone_label', __( 'Phone', 'wpsl' ) ) ) . '</strong>: <%= formatPhoneNumber( phone ) %>(1)</span>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% } %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% if ( fax ) { %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<span><strong>' . esc_html( $wpsl->i18n->get_translation( 'fax_label', __( 'Fax', 'wpsl' ) ) ) . '</strong>: <%= fax %>(2)</span>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% } %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% if ( email ) { %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<span><strong>' . esc_html( $wpsl->i18n->get_translation( 'email_label', __( 'Email', 'wpsl' ) ) ) . '</strong>: <%= formatEmail( email ) %>(3)</span>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% } %>' . "\r\n";

    /**
     * Include the data from a custom field called 'my_textinput'.
     * 
     * Before you can access the 'my_textinput' data in the template, 
     * you first need to make sure the data is included in the JSON output.
     * 
     * You can make the data accessible through the wpsl_frontend_meta_fields filter.
     * 
     * 
     */

    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% if ( my_textinput ) { %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<p><%= my_textinput %></p>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% } %>' . "\r\n";

    $info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<%= createInfoWindowActions( id ) %>' . "\r\n";
    $info_window_template .= "\t" . '</div>' . "\r\n";

    return $info_window_template;
}
```

When I add the following piece of code (almost a the end) the info windows doesn't show:

```
$info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% if ( my_textinput ) { %>' . "\r\n";
$info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<p><%= my_textinput %></p>' . "\r\n";
$info_window_template .= "\t\t" . '<% } %>' . "\r\n";
```

And I am getting the following error on DevTool console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: my_textinput is not defined
    at eval (eval at m.template (underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3:5), <anonymous>:52:2)
    at c (underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3:5)
    at H (wpsl-gmap.min.js?ver=2.2.15:1)
    at _.ze.<anonymous> (wpsl-gmap.min.js?ver=2.2.15:1)
    at Object.trigger ...
```

How can I make sure the data is included in the JSON output?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 filters which need to use to achieve it.

1. wpsl_meta_box_fields
2. wpsl_frontend_meta_fields
3. wpsl_info_window_template

wpsl_frontend_meta_fields filter used to add custom field in frontend json.

The mentioned error means custom field my_textinput is not added in to frontend json. Please check if you are using cache. If yes please clear cache from settings. For this navigate go to Tools section in Store Locator settings page and Clear store locator transient cache.
[Clear transient cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFweQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to also add a filter to `custom_frontend_meta_fields` like this:

```
add_filter( 'wpsl_frontend_meta_fields', 'custom_frontend_meta_fields' );

function custom_frontend_meta_fields( $store_fields ) {

    $store_fields['wpsl_my_textinput] = array(
        'name' => 'my_textinput',
        'type' => 'text'
    );
```

Type can be URL, phone, text... you can see the documentation [here](https://wpstorelocator.co/document/add-custom-meta-data-to-store-locations/)